# Is is possible to build codes using Bazel in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tensorflow, bazel

I'm currently following [this instruction](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f) to build C++ code with `tensorflow`.

What I want to do is to run the execution (binary) file with Visual Studio's `debug` mode.

To do this, I think I have to build a binary file via `Visual Studio` first so that I can set a breakpoint and execute the code line by line.

But problem is that building the code in `VS` is not that simple because it uses `bazel` command instead of `g++`.

Is is possible to build codes using Bazel in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

As of version 0.22.0, there is no plugin support for Visual Studio: see [list of supported IDEs and editors](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.22.0/ide.html).

There is, however, [an API to build IDE plugins](https://blog.bazel.build/2016/06/10/ide-support.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, https://github.com/tmandry/lavender has been published. This is a project generator that generates a Visual Studio Solution file and project files given Bazel build files (WORKSPACE, BUILD, etc.). Also debugging works surprisingly well.