# How to go about integrating mediapipe's Pose Tracking into an existing Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, deep-learning, computer-vision

I must admit that I am quite a newb when it comes to build systems. So far I've managed to build the hello_word and the Pose Tracking examples on Windows (going through quite a few hoops along the way)
https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows

Of course, building those examples gives me an executable, which I can't integrate in another project.

What I'd like to do is have mediapipe as a dll or something similar so I can pass the framework an image and get joint coordinates in return, ideally. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am going to use this Pose Tracking project

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/tree/master/mediapipe/examples/desktop/pose_tracking

https://github.com/google/mediapipe
written in C ++ language in Visual Studio 2019 for another project in C #. I built it through Bazel in Windows 10 according to the document instructions and output a file.exe gave me I can not use this source code in .cc format in Visual Studio 2019 I wanted to help me how can I compile projects that I compile through Bazel I can use in Visual Studio.
I found the following links but unfortunately the output which is in the form of sln project 2019  file in C ++ did not give me output.

[Is is possible to build codes using Bazel in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106563/is-is-possible-to-build-codes-using-bazel-in-visual-studio/48286536#48286536)